# Reading CSV file with special characters from Europe and Latin America in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, encoding

I have a file with special characters I believe from Europe and Latin America.
I did pd.read_csv("file.csv", encoding='iso8859')
It read some special characters. But characters like "Ãœs" still was "Ãs", "Ã„rz" was "Ãrz".There is a bunch of those.
Any idea what to use for encoding? I used iso8859, iso8859-1,iso8859-15. Latin-1, UTF8,UTF16.

Answer (score 0):

You can try different Encodings in Pandas:

```
encodings_to_try = ['utf-8', 'latin1', 'iso-8859-1', 'iso-8859-15', 'cp1252']

for enc in encodings_to_try:
    try:
        df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', encoding=enc)
        print(f'Successfully read with encoding: {enc}')
        break
    except:
        print(f'Failed with encoding: {enc}')
```

Answer (score 0):

It would first be helpful to check out background on file encodings in general; [this](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) is a great resource as well as the official Python [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings). It's first helpful to *know* exactly what your file is encoded as rather than trying to read it in different ways.

Pandas also has an encoding explanation in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) for `read_csv` -- of note is that the default is `utf-8`. If you've exhausted those, sometimes its simpler to apply a function from a 'fixer' library such as [this](https://ftfy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) after reading in your data with a standard encoding such as the default.